# Как объединить классы в java? Как с этих кусков кода сделать один проект?

Tags: java, классы

```
public class TypeByte {
private static int j;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 3;
    byte b = 1, 
        b1 = 1 + 2;
        //b = b1 + 1; //ошибка приведения типов
           b = (byte)(b1 + 1);//0
            show(b);
            //b = -b; //ошибка приведения типов
           b = (byte)-b;//1
            show(b);
            //b = +b1; //ошибка приведения типов
           b = (byte)+b1; //2
    show(b);
           b1 *= 2; //3
    show(b1);
           b1++; //4
            show(b1);
            //b = i; //ошибка приведения типов
           b = (byte)i; //5
    show(b);
       b += i++; //работает!!!  //6
    show(b);
             float f = 1.1f;
           b /= f; //работает!!!  //7
            show(b);
}
static void show(byte b){
    System.out.println(j + " res=" + b);
    j++;
    }
 }



public class Types {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Float f = new Float(10.01); //double в Float
String s1 = Float.toString(0f); //float в String
String s2 = String.valueOf(f); //Float в String
    Byte b = Byte.valueOf("120"); //String в Byte 
    double d = b.doubleValue(); // Byte в double
    short s = (short) d; // double в short 
    Character ch = new Character('3');
  /*Character в int */      
  int i = Character.digit(ch.charValue(), 10); 
    System.out.println("s1=" + s1 + ", s2=" + s2);
  System.out.print("b=" + b + ", s=" + s + ", d=" + d + ", i=" + i);
   }
 }



  public class Operators {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("5%1=" + 5%1 + "  5%2=" + 5%2);
    int b1 = 0xe;//14 или 1110
    int b2 = 0x9;//9  или 1001
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(b1 + "|" + b2 + " = " + (b1|b2));
    System.out.println(b1 + "&" + b2 + " = " + (b1&b2));
     System.out.println(b1 + "^" + b2 + " = " + (b1^b2));
      System.out.println(     "~" + b2 + " = " + ~b2);
       System.out.println(b1 + ">>" + ++i + " = " + (b1>>i));
         System.out.println(b1 + "<<" + i + " = " + (b1<<i++));
         System.out.println(b1 + ">>>" + i +" = " + (b1>>>i));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос: Каких классов, если он один? Каких кусков кода?

Comment: У меня есть три класса (TypeByte, Types, Operators). Код каждого класса я написала, отдельными проектами работает, в одном проекте нет.

Comment: Из кода и вопроса не понятно какую цель вы преследуете. Если просто объединить файлы, то ctrl+c cltr+v вам в помощь. Иначе поясните как эти классы должны взаимодействовать и что вообще делает ваш проект.

Comment: Чтобы этого добиться вам требуется освоить базовые принципы ООП, разнести данные по полям и логику по методам, оставив в единственном методе `main` всего пару-тройку строк кода. Сейчас ваш код сложно назвать даже процедурным.